# Switching website's folder from www to non-www using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Hi although this question is asked many times but my question is a little different and I tried many thing but couldn't complete it.

I have a website running in wordpress at domain say "http://example.com" and another website at "/jobs" folder (a simple core php website). Now my problem is when ever the user land on "http://www.example.com/jobs" and its inner links, the redirections using our jquery do not work since for the redirections we are using URL as base url without 'www'.

Now how can i possibly switch my website from www to non-www for only folder and all its inner folders using htaccess.

Htaccess of our Root website:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress


<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Pragma
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    <FilesMatch ".(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|swf|xml)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
        \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </filesmatch>
</ifModule>
```

Htaccess of our /jobs folder:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home1/project_name/public_html/jobs
<Files php.ini>order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /jobs/?location[]=$1&q=$2&bookMark=$3&scrollFlag=$4&countScroll=$5&sort=$6 [L]

RewriteRule ^companies/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  /jobs/joblisting.php?comp_id=$1&jobRole=$2&pgno=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^companies/(.*)/(.*)$  /jobs/joblisting.php?comp_id=$1&pgno=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^companies/(.*)$  /jobs/joblisting.php?comp_id=$1 [L]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Pragma
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    <FilesMatch ".(js|css)$">
    #set max-age for 1 YEAR
        #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, private"
    #set max-age for NEVER CACHE
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</ifModule>

# log PHP errors to a file
# File modified on Tue Feb 25 22:07:48 2014 by server
# For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
# php_flag log_errors on
# File modified on Tue Feb 25 22:07:52 2014 by server
# For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
# php_value error_log "/php_errors.log"



<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just match the jobs folder in the main .htaccess to not use www with this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/jobs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or if you want all in one line.

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.*)$ http://example.com/jobs/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but unfortunately it didn't work in my case.

Comment: I have 2 htaccess files one in jobs folder and another is on the main domain. I tried placing the code on the both .htaccess files. but none of them

Comment: Your first code works at some point but when website redirect on http://example.com/jobs/$1 it keep on redirecting and browser show error message for the same.

Comment: Ok then Edit you question and post the contents of you htaccess files or there really isn't way to help.